# Same class different package and JAXB

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I hace several .xsd and I want to generate classes with JAXB.

```
Package: v1
Class: JBObject
Class: ...

Package: v2
Class JBObject
Class: ...
```

I use a factory pattern, if it's v1 I use the classes of v1 and if it's v2 I use the classes of v2.
In a version I have to use the classes of package 1 and in other version I have to use the classes of package 2.
The classes generated are the same or almost the same.

I have other class called Translation with the method:

```
import XX.JBObject;
public void translate(JBObject object)
{
    ...
    String name = object.getName();
    JBRelationObject relationObject = object.getRelationObject();
    int id = relationObject.getId();
    ...
}
```

JBObject is the same class in v1 and v2 but I have to import in the class and I don't want to copy and paste twice (one with each import)
How can I solve it?

With import I mean: import v1.JBObject; or import v2.JBObject;

Comment: What do you mean by "import in" the method?

Comment: import v1.JBObject; or import v2.JBObject;

Comment: Those are imports of *classes*. You said you "have to import in the *method* `translate`", which makes no sense. Are you saying that you want your `translate` method in your `Translation` class to work on either version of `JBObject`, without creating two versions of the `translate` method?

Comment: Yes. That's the point. I don't want to create the same method twice.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options.

*Option 1:* Make both `JBObject` classes implement the same interface.
Since they are generated, you probably can't do that.

*Option 2:* Wrap them with adapter classes that implement common interface.
This is useful if you need shared logic in multiple places.

*Option 3:* If all your `translate()` method needs is `JBObject.getName()`, get the name and delegate to common code, e.g.

```
public void translate(v1.JBObject jb1obj) {
    translate(jb1obj.getName());
}
public void translate(v2.JBObject jb2obj) {
    translate(jb2obj.getName());
}
private void translate(String name) {
    // common logic here
}
```

No `import` statement. Your code handles both versions in a single class.

Comment: I have more than getName it was an example. I like option 2 but the problem is that I have +/- 100 classes so I would have to create a lot of interfaces (I have a lot of methods like translate with other object). Thank you.

Comment: And I have more objects like JBObject. For Example, in JBObject I have JBRelationObject getJBRelationObjet() and setJBRelationObject(JBRelationObject relationObject) so how can I do the interfaces in that cases?